# dns_get_record in foreach loop to check domain avaiblity

Tags: php

I'm creating a simple script to check a domain avaiblity. I would like to use dns_get_record fo this, because it's fast.

dns_get_record is working fine with one domain check

```
$dom = dns_get_record('example.com', DNS_ALL);
print_r($dom);
```

but when I put it in loop I get only empty arrays.

```
$arr = explode("\n",$_POST['lista_domen']);
var_dump($arr);


foreach($arr AS $domena)
{
     var_dump($domena);

     $response = dns_get_record($domena, DNS_ALL);

     var_dump($response);

     //print_r($response);
     if(empty($response)){
     echo "<H2 style='color:green;'>Domain $domena is available.</H2>";
     }else{
     echo "<H2 style='color:red;'>Domain $domena has taken.</H2>";
     }


}


}
```

and I get message that all domains are available.

```
line 28:         $response = dns_get_record($domena, DNS_ALL);
```

> **Edit: Deleted @ and var_dumped variables:**
>
> I put in form 2 domains (interia.pl, onet.pl, ). Last one is blank.
>
> **var_dump($arr)**: array(3) { [0]=> string(9) "wykop.pl " [1]=> string(8) "onet.pl " [2]=> string(0) "" }
>
> **var_dump($domena)**: string(9) "wykop.pl " Warning: dns_get_record(): DNS Query failed in D:\Programy\xampp\htdocs\whois2\index.php on line
>   28
>
> **var_dump($response)**:
>   bool(false)
>
> **var_dump($domena)**: string(8) "onet.pl " Warning: dns_get_record(): DNS Query failed in D:\Programy\xampp\htdocs\whois2\index.php on line
>   28
>
> **var_dump($response)**: bool(false)

Comment: i suspect the underlying implementation ([librsolv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)) is not thread safe, [discussion](http://www.verycomputer.com/168_83542999b0a29a15_1.htm#p1). but i'm not sure. hope someone else will explain better.

Comment: First inspect your $arr better. Watch for all characters, like \r. ARe you sure they are not in the input from the $_POST? Second: What will be the value of $response if your @ errorsupression surpresses an error?

Comment: 1) Start by getting rid of the error suppression. 2) `var_dump` all relevant values and narrow it down to reproducible examples. 3) Tangential: [don't use `empty` when `!` will do just fine.](http://kunststube.net/isset)

Comment: @ErwinMoller yea, there is a blank one domain at the end (\r) but that's not problem, it just shows blank domain at the end of script. Domain before that blank one should work fine. I just edited post and added var dumps.

Comment: I am not convinced. I expect a \r in each element of your array. You can try to trim it before using to get rid of it. Like: $response = dns_get_record(trim($domena), DNS_ALL);

Comment: @ErwinMoller Yep, you were right. It's working now. Thanks :)